# Is Heroku rendering React components very slowly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, heroku, server

Basically I've deployed my React app using Heroku. The problem is, it is not performing nearly as well as it was on localhost. For example, I have an "animation player" component that displays an image and updates it using a setInterval. At local dev level, it runs a smooth 40 fps, but when I tried my app after deploying it, it's running at maybe 2 fps. I don't understand how this can be since I thought React components are rendered by the browser engine and have nothing to do with the Heroku servers? Would upgrading my account or switching to some other web service improve my app's performance? Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: _"I thought React components are ran by the browser engine and have nothing to do with the Heroku servers?"_ - that's usually\* correct, Heroku just serves the static build outputs (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.) and everything else runs in your users' browsers. _\* unless some form of server-side rendering is being used_

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe, thanks for the reply. Then is there any difference between running React on localhost vs on the web?

Comment: If you run a development instance then yes, on prod you serve a built app. 
If you want us to inspect more why its slow perhaps you shall link the hero instance

Comment: Have you checked what's happening with performance in the dev tools? `setInterval` has [some odd side-effects](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) which you may want to look into.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "running". Often for working locally you'll be using a dev server with things like file watching and hot reloading, whereas in production you just serve the static files. But you can also serve the static files locally to see if it's a dev-vs-build issue (e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#static-server).

Comment: I think I figured it out, the problem was I was fetching images from the servers haha, which means the rerendering interval is shorter than the time it takes to fetch the image. Might be off topic, but what would be the best process to download the images so that they can be accessed quicker? (maybe localstorage?)

Comment: Fundamentally they have to get from the server to the client _somehow_, even if you then put them into local storage. You might find moving the images out to a dedicated CDN helps a bit.

Comment: @19e9030393 Use a video file instead of lots of images that have to be loaded individually. If you need to use images, prefetch them before the animation starts; and make sure to send the correct HTTP caching headers.